# How do I remove the TeamViewer Outlook Add-In?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, teamviewer

After installing TeamViewer, I now have an Add-In installed in Outlook, which, supposedly, lets me create new TeamViewer meetings.

I never wanted to have that Add-In and now I want to get rid of it. Sadly, I can't find *how*.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

### TeamViewer Option

The easiest way is probably to do it through TeamViewer.

1. Start TeamViewer and open the **Options**.

   [image: TeamViewer]
2. Go to the **Advanced** section and click **Show advanced options**.

   [image: Advanced section]
3. Near the bottom of the panel, you'll find a button labeled **Deactivate Outlook Add-In**. Click it to deactivate the Add-In.

   [image: Deactivate Outlook Add-In]

### Outlook Option

1. Go to **File** → **Options**.
2. Go to the **Add-Ins** section.
3. At the bottom of the dialog, select **COM-Add-Ins** from the dropdown and click the **Go** button.
4. Uncheck the **TeamViewer Meeting Add-In** to deactivate it for your user account.

Answer (score 2):

There are better options than just disabling the add-in/plug-in.

## Outlook

1. Start Outlook as administrator.
2. Navigate to File -> Options -> Add-ins.
3. Locate Manage: COM Add-ins -> Go.
4. Select TeamViewer Add-in. Click Remove.
5. Close Outlook and start as regular user.

TeamViewer setup does provide an option to not use Outlook add-in under "Advanced Settings", but that still installs the add-in in disabled state. I wish they had chosen not to install it at all when user does not want it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Teamviewer .MSI version  (if you have a corporate license), please add the following registry key to your .reg file to disable the Outlook Plug-in during the MSI deployment: (This might require access to the original installer for the add-in.)

32bit:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\TeamViewerOutlookAddIn]   
"LoadBehavior"=dword:00000002
```

64bit:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\TeamViewerOutlookAddIn]
"LoadBehavior"=dword:00000002
```

Unfortunately, the keys generated by TeamViewer interface don't include these to disable the add-on on deployment; therefore, the above mentioned method is required.

I got this info from Teamviewer support a long time ago (we also have this disabled enterprise-wide) and can confirm this works.